# Riemann sums to calculate the area of a triangle

Tags: integration, area, riemann-sum

Consider a triangle in the 1st quadrant defined by

\begin{align}
&x \geq 0 \\
&y \geq 0 \\
&y = 1-x 
\end{align}

To calculate the area using double integrals we could for example take
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{1-y} dxdy = [y-\frac{y^2}{2}]_{0}^1 = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
as expected.
I am wondering how to reach this answer using Riemann sums ie defining the area as
\begin{align}
A = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^m \Delta x_i \Delta y_j
\end{align}
In particular how do we set $m$ to be the discretized limit $x \leq 1-y$ ?

Comment: The heck are we using double integrals for!? For a single Reimann sum, we can just use one rectangle with a midpoint sum.

Comment: It's part of a bigger problem of finding the number of squares of a given size that fit under a function. I thought of the problem as essentially being a discretized version of a double integral hence why I want to investigate a simpler problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Define Let $x_i$, $y_j$ be the points in the domain associated with the Riemann summands. Then:

\begin{align}
A = \lim_{n,m \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^m \Delta x_i \Delta y_j \mathbf{1}[1-{y}_j \geq {x}_i],
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{1}[B]= 1$, if $B$ is true and $=0$ otherwise.

When using the same Riemann-partition for $x$ and $y$, one can simplify 
$$A = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^{n(1-y_j)} \Delta x_i \Delta y_j 
$$